Given a representation $(n, m)$ of the Lorentz group, is the little group representation just the tensor product $n \otimes m$?
I've been reading Weinberg's QFT Vol 1. and more specifically section 5.6. I would like to know if my understanding is correct or if I missed something. He starts with the full Lorentz group $\mathrm{SO}(3, 1)$ and shows that we have two commuting copies of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ generators $A_i$ and $B_i$. He then says that the 'rotation group' is generated by $J_i = A_i + B_i$. Is the 'rotation group' the same thing as the little group (for massive particles)?
These $J_i$ then form a representation of the tensor product $V_A \otimes V_B$ of the two $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ irreps $V_A, V_B$ (if I remember correctly). Is it correct to say then, that given some irrep of the Lorentz group $(A, B)$ the corresponding representation of the little group is nothing but $V_A \otimes V_B$?
His examples seem to confirm this, e.g. a vector $(1/2, 1/2)$ would then be in the $1 \oplus 0$ representation of the (universal cover) of the little group $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, but he doesn't state it this way which makes me wary.


Consider the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(3,1;\mathbb{R})$ and its complexification $$SO(3,1;\mathbb{C}).\tag{1}$$ Picking the COM frame the massive little group becomes the 3D rotation group $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$.

The double covers are isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$,
$$G~:=~SL(2,\mathbb{C})_L\times SL(2,\mathbb{C})_R\tag{2}$$ and $H:=SU(2)$, respectively, cf. e.g. this Phys.SE post.

The (double cover of the) little group $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ via the diagonal imbedding
$$H~\ni~h\quad\mapsto\quad(h,h)~\in~G.\tag{3}$$

If $\rho: G\to GL(V)$ is a group representation for $G$, it induces a restricted representation $\rho|_H:H\to GL(V)$ on the subgroup $H$.

For an irreducible $G$-representation
$$(j_L,j_R)~=~j_L\otimes j_R, \qquad 
j_L, j_R~\in~ \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0,\tag{4}$$
the restricted $H$-representation is
$$j_L\otimes j_R~\cong~\oplus_{j=|j_L-j_r|}^{j_L+j_R} j,\tag{5}$$
as mentioned in OP's title. Note that the notation in expression (4) and (5) are deceptively similar. However we stress that it is implicitly implied that expression (4) is a $G$-representation, while expression (5) is an $H$-representation.



I am not going to read Weinberg's book with you to your satisfaction, nor should I.
Indeed, the little group of a massive particle (go to its rest frame) is the rotation group SO(3), sharing a Lie algebra with SU(2).
Presumably, your text has reminded you,  like (A2) of this, that for an so(1,3) irrep π labelled by integer of half-integer spins (n,m), the three coproduct operators
$$
 \pi_{(n,m)}(J_i) = J^{(m)}_i \otimes {\mathbb I}_{(2n+1)}+{\mathbb I}_{(2m+1)} \otimes J^{(n)}_i 
$$
manifestly satisfy the so(3)~su(2) Lie algebra commutation relations. (This is just the rotation subgroup of the Lorentz group, the little group.) Check it again.
These operators are huge matrices acting on
$(2n+1)\times (2m+1)$-dimensional vectors, so the tensor product reducible representation you get by "adding" spins n and m in elementary QM, as you properly exemplify.
Moreover,  your text should have exemplified that the likewise huge,
$(2n+1)\times (2m+1)$ by $(2n+1)\times (2m+1)$ -dimensional,  group matrices
$$
e^{i\vec \theta \cdot (\vec J^{(m)} \otimes {\mathbb I}_{(2n+1)}+{\mathbb I}_{(2m+1)} \otimes \vec J^{(n)} )} =
e^{i\vec \theta \cdot \vec J^{(m)} }
  \otimes   e^{i\vec \theta \cdot   \vec J^{(n)}  }
$$
provide the conventional reducible representation of the rotation group of QM.
